# What's wrong with this threads pool / multi-core simulation

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Hy everyone. I've been trying to make a kind of threads pool, meant to simulate a multi-core processor, where I have a number of threads running all the time( the core ), that I later dispatch to process a ( fixed for now) function. The idea to have the threads running at all time is that I don't have the thread creation/destruction overhead.
There are three problems with what I'm doing now.
First, the results are all wrong.
Second, the function measuring the time is reporting 0 ms
Third, the program calls abort at exit.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
    auto fakeExpensiveOperation = [](int i) -> float
    {
        Sleep(10);
        return sqrt(i);
    };

    // Performance test
    int size = 4000;
    float* out = new float[size];

#define THREAD_RUNNING 0
#define THREAD_FINISHED (1 << 0)
#define THREAD_EXIT (1 << 1)
#define THREAD_STALL (1 << 2)

    const int coreCount = 8;
    thread cores[coreCount];
    atomic<unsigned int> msgArray[coreCount]; for (auto& msg : msgArray) msg.store(THREAD_STALL);

    auto kernel = [out, &fakeExpensiveOperation](int idx){ out[idx] = fakeExpensiveOperation(idx); };
    for (int i = 0; i < coreCount; i++)
    {
        cores[i] = thread([&msgArray, i, kernel]()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                unsigned int msg = msgArray[i].load();

                if((msg & THREAD_STALL) == THREAD_STALL)
                    continue;

                if ((msg & THREAD_EXIT) == THREAD_EXIT)
                    break;

                if ((msg & THREAD_RUNNING) == THREAD_RUNNING)
                {
                    int idx = (msg >> 3) + i;

                    // Do the function
                    kernel(idx);

                    msgArray[i].store(THREAD_FINISHED);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    auto t2 = time_call([&]()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i += coreCount)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < coreCount; n++)
            {
                if((msgArray[n].load() & THREAD_RUNNING) == THREAD_RUNNING) continue; // The core is still working

                unsigned int msg = THREAD_RUNNING;
                msg |= (i << 3);
                msgArray[n].store(msg);
            }
        }
    });
    for (int n = 0; n < coreCount; n++) msgArray[n].store(THREAD_EXIT);

    cout << "sqrt 0 : " << out[0] << endl;
    cout << "sqrt 1 : " << out[1] << endl;
    cout << "sqrt 2 : " << out[2] << endl;
    cout << "sqrt 4 : " << out[4] << endl;
    cout << "sqrt 16 : " << out[16] << endl;

    cout << "Parallel : " << t2 << endl;
    system("pause");
    delete[] out;
    return 0;
```

I'm really out of ideas. Can anyone point out what's wrong here?

EDIT: I did the changes i mentioned, and still get wrong values. I changed the values of the flags, and detached the threads after creating them.

Comment: Since `THREAD_RUNNING` is 0, `(foo & THREAD_RUNNING) == THREAD_RUNNING` is a complicated way to write `true`.

Comment: You never `join` or `detach` your threads, so `std::terminate` is called when their destructors run.

Comment: You are both right! :facepalm. I should detach the threads, and change the value in THREAD_RUNNING. I can't try it now, but i'll try it later.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, (I'm not greatly familiar with the C++11 threading stuff) but it looks like you running a thread `cores[i] = thread([&msgArray, i, kernel]()` then waiting until that thread is done.  Then creating the next thread.  Essentially making it single threaded.

I also like using this for timing with C++11

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;

start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

// Do Stuff

end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds_d1 = end-start;
std::time_t end_time_d1 = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds_d1.count() << "s\n";
```

Comment: Actually, what I'm doing is first create the threads, and then set the work they have to do. See also my comment to the first post.